# How to trace a user's location?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

currently I am working on an activities management system, in this application I want to give facility to show the visitor location of this site. I am using c# and asp.net 
so how we should start implementation can any one will suggest.....

```
                                                                    Thanks
                                                                    Nishant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you users will have browsers that support HTML 5 you can use the GeoLocation API that comes with HTML 5 (see http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html)

Additionally there are several companies/products that provide ways to determine a user location based on their IP address address and other request values. It's not always accurate but they would get you close enough.

Answer (score 2):

We looked at a bunch of them,  they all ended up kinda like IP2Location.

Honestly the results were sometimes great, sometimes not even close.  On top of that most vendors charge by lookup, and the costs were very prohibited.

If you are just looking for analytics, implement Google Analytics.  Its free and has a visitor map inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try MaxiMind GeoIP engine:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/installation?city=1

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jakub, Maxmind is a good bet for accurate locations. Most of the online tracers and software actually use Maxmind anyway.

Dan

http://www.visualiptrace.com/websitetrace.html